# Cross Compile apache server for arm-linux

Tags: arm, embedded-linux

now a days I am working with my arm-1808 board and want to cross compile Apache web server for it.I have already tried different instructions to do this but did not get the satisfied results please help me . Thanks

Comment: Do you _absolutely_ need Apache HTTP Server? Wouldn't [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) be enough? I cross-compiled this for an embedded system and it went very well. It builds easily as a static executable and only needs a small configuration file at boot time in order to work.

Comment: can u please mention those steps which you were followed ?

Comment: @KevinVermeer  there is no any error in compilation but when i try to port it on my arm-1808 then come up with this  error:-./httpd: line 1: syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: @Hasnat - Please put this information in the question!  As it stands, your current question doesn't meet quality standards. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by 'port' - to me, that word means the activity of modifying the configuration and code to be able to run on a new architecture.  If you've gotten to `./httpd` then you're done porting and on to debugging.

Comment: @eepp i have also compiled the lighttpd for my arm-1808 but will you please tell me how it works on it ?

Comment: I think this is not part of the question anymore. lighttpd is very easy to use; just go read some guides/introductions on its official website. If it's compiled and starts with no linking error, you should get a working HTTP server in a matter of minutes.